# Yii Framework force Save as dialog

Tags: php, header, yii

I am building a web application using Yii. The application generates MS-Word documents. Does anyone can give me a hint on how to force the browser to open a save as dialog.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to send these headers:

```
header("Pragma: no-cache"); // required
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private", false); // required for certain browsers
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"test.doc\"");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
```

This sends the file as test.doc download.

Comment: thanks for the answer, it actually works. I put your code in a controller's function, which I call it using a CHtml::link. However, it does not work when I use a button. I need to send some POST parameters and perform an action in the onClick event.